# Angular directive disposal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to perform cleanup on different angular directives.

I have different types of directives, some do not define their own scope, some have an isolated scope, and some have a child scope.

I need a generic mechanism that will take care of the cleanup in a separate component that my directives use.

So basically I'm looking at two different options, either register on angular's `element.on('$destroy', function() {...})` or on jquery's `scope.$on('$destroy', function () {...})`.

Here's the problem:
If I register on the underlying element destruction then I miss destruction of directives that they're element was not destructed (not sure exactly how's that possible, noticed it via testing...).
If I register on the underlying scope destruction then (I think) I miss destruction of directives that they're element was destructed, for instance when the directive is not defining its own scope and is using its parent scope.

Looking at angular's directives documentation I came across this:

> Best Practice: Directives should clean up after themselves. You can use element.on('$destroy', ...) or scope.$on('$destroy', ...) to run a clean-up function when the directive is removed.

There's no mention as far as I can tell about which strategy to use when.

Also, looking at Angular's documentation I came across this:

> When child scopes are no longer needed, it is the responsibility of the child scope creator to destroy them via scope.$destroy() API.

I don't understand the scenario in which I am supposed to call the scope.$destroy() API on my own.

Comment: The Doc says *it is the responsibility of the child scope creator*. Are your directives creating child scopes? Are your directives removing elements?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).